# Vuetify: use carousel to display components

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

The response to [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/181) issue says:

> The slot is missing from the docs, you can already do this.

Can someone provide a toy example or explanation of *how* to do this?  To clarify, what I want is to import components (eg. A.vue, B.vue, C.vue) into another (eg. Carousel.vue), then display said components in a carousel.  Something along the lines of:

```
<template>
  <v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(component, i) in components"></v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>

<script>
  import A from '@/components/A'
  import B from '@/components/B'
  import C from '@/components/C'

  export default {
    components: {
      A,
      B,
      C
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Well basically issues says if you include your components properly, you can just put them inside `v-carousel` e.g.  `<v-carousel> <your-custom-component/>  </v-carousel>`.  Or inside item also: `<v-carousel-item>
        <v-btn>Hi</v-btn>
      </v-carousel-item>` What's not working?

Comment: @Traxo great, thanks.  So, I got something working by putting my custom components inside `<v-carousel-item>` tags.  If you want to post a solution, I'll accept it.  Otherwise I'll post what I've written as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue says if you include your components properly, you can just put them inside `v-carousel` e.g.

```
<v-carousel>
     <your-custom-component/>
</v-carousel>
```

Or inside `v-carousel-item` also

```
<v-carousel-item>
    <v-btn>Hi</v-btn>
</v-carousel-item>
```

---

In order to make `<your-custom-component/>` work inside `<v-carousel>`, top level component inside `<your-custom-component/>` must be `v-carousel-item`:

```
// YourCustomComponent.vue
<template>
    <v-carousl-item>
    // ...
    </v-carousl-item>
</template>
```

(That is unless something has changed in subsequent versions of vuetify)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because part of the suggestion is correct, but @Traxo you might want to edit it for posterity (?). In my poking at the code, I found that `<v-carousel><custom-component/></v-carousel>` _DOES NOT_ work.  However, <v-carousel><v-carousel-item><custom-component/></v-carousel-item></v-carousel>` _does_.  The latter is what I ended up implementing.

Comment: @wayeast Well it works, for example if `your-custom-component` is `v-carousl-item`, it was not clear to me from your question what you were trying to achieve, or what was not working, so I just put it as example.

Comment: Can down-voter explain why they think that this answer was not useful?

Comment: Hello, I'm a  bit confused by this answer because as I read the question he would like to show three different components at different pages? Like first I see component A, I click right and will see component B. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: @xhist But the OP already provided code for that I think? The issue was just that his components were not properly structured as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are OK with dropping the `carousel` requirement, then you may want to take a look at [v-window](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/windows). It provides exactly what you are asking for.